# Sort String[] in android?

Tags: android

```
String[] names = { "Capacitance", "Current", "Capacitive Reactance",
            "Energy", "Frequency", "Inductance", "Inductive Reactance",
            "Power", "PowerFactor Angle", "RealPower", "ReactivePower",
            "Resistance", "SysytemFrequency", "Voltage" };
```

How to Sort this Array.Any one Please Help me.

Answer (score 5):

Try below code.

**Sort array in ascending order**

```
Arrays.sort(names);
```

**Sort array in descending order**

```
Arrays.sort(names, Collections.reverseOrder());
```